# xUnit detect discovery vs running tests

Tags: c#, xunit

Is it possible for the code in Theory Memberdata function to detect weather xUnit is doing discovery vs running the tests ?  Is there some run-time switch that one could check for.

Comment: Why do you need that? Besides, xUnit is open source, so you might take a look at its code base and do some experiments.

Comment: Because I'm cheating.  I have a wrapper for running RSpec tests from VS and under CI builds that will bring the Rspec test results back to the environment.  This way the devs can run the tests from VS instead of having to run them on the command line.  To save time, I only want to shoot off RSpec once and run all test in a directory instead of once for each test.  Although I don't want to run the tests during discovery, just return the test names.  I did poke around with the xunit code on Github before but I couldn't figure it out, I will have to dig deeper.

Comment: As I can see it is not trivial a request, you probably should open an issue at xUnit GitHub repo to utilize the expertise of the authors. SO is not a suitable place.

Answer (score 0):

Brad Wilson one of the xunit authors answered this on the [xunit github](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/1461).

--> There is not, though if you want to prevent enumeration during discovery, you can see DisableDiscoveryEnumeration = true on the [MemberData] attribute.